# All indexes of string-array return null

Tags: c#, arrays, string, indexing

I've been coding in C# (winforms) for a project for 2 weeks now. My goal is to build a GUI for an FFT-Analysis (frequency-realm).

**my Problem:**

I keep running into the same problem: i receive 1024 int values (one blocksize) separated by white spaces in one string via serial port and then terminated by \n into a buffer uart_buf. To obtain numeric values, i use uart_buf.split(' ') into a string[] parse_buf and then try to access a single value in ASCII-format like this: parse_buf[i] = val_buf. This i then try to form into a numeric via value = int.Parse(val_buf), without success: System.ArgumentNullException: value cant be NULL.

**What I've tried:**

- value = int.Parse(parse_buf[i]); This returns a format exception
- printing parse_buf[i] to a textbox shows an expected value (the received data is correct)
- observing the main buffer uart_buf shows valid data like this: "41 30 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 40 500 69..."
- starting from index 1 (or any other) instead of 0 changes nothing

**What I don't get:**

A single element (ergo a string) of parse_buf contains a value in text-form, e.g. "41". I want to save it to a regular string val_buf, which i should be able to parse to int. Why is every string accessed via parse_buf[i] null?

**Code-Fragments:**

```
        private void displayData(object o, EventArgs e)
    {
        parse_buf = uart_buf.Split(' ');
        tb_data.Text = parse_buf[0]; //this shows valid data in a tb
        for (i = 1; i < parse_buf.Length; i++)  //about 1024 loops
        {
            //problem area:
            parse_buf[i] = val_buf;
            fft = int.Parse(val_buf);

            //ignore this:
            f = i * 20;
            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(f, fft);
        }
    }
```

I usually work in C with embeded systems, so sorry for not seeing the problem instantly. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect `parse_buf[i] = val_buf;` is meant to be `val_buf= parse_buf[i];`. It's a bit hard to tell as we don't know the intended purpose of `val_buf` or where it's declared. (Why are you using it at all? Why not just use `fft = int.Parse(parse_buf[i]);`? And why is `fft` apparently a field instead of a local variable? Ditto `val_buf` and `parse_buf`. Prefer local variables where possible.)

Comment: Aside from anything else, I'd strongly recommend following .NET naming conventions when writing .NET code.

Comment: Additionaly, you probably want to start your loop at index 0, because currently you are missing the first element in the array.

Comment: As derpischer pointed out, the index ist wrong, that was left from a previous experiment. It is now starting from 0 again.

Comment: Like Jon Skeet mentioned, parse_buf[i] = val_buf is not only wrongly flipped, but also unnecessary; it has been removed. Still, like i mentioned under "things i tried": value = int.Parse(parse_buf[i]); This returns a format exception, wrong format. What is it expecting other than a string?

Comment: `parse_buf[i] = val_buf;` -> `val_buf = parse_buf[i];`

Comment: if you get a format exception, it means that the string you are trying to parse is not a number (or better, a string representation of a number). you can try using int.TryParse and printing the value when it returns false]

Answer (score 0):

```cs
private void DisplayData(object o, EventArgs e)
{
    parse_buf = uart_buf.Split(' ');
    tb_data.Text = parse_buf[0]; //this shows valid data in a tb
    
    for (i = 0; i < parse_buf.Length; i++)  //about 1024 loops
    {
        //problem area:
        int.TryParse(parse_buf[i], out ftt);

        //ignore this:
        chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(i * 20, fft);
    }
}
```